# Concatenating 3D arrays with different dimensions on axis 2

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm attempting to put together a number of 3D arrays with the same size on the first two dimensions but differing sizes on the 3rd dimensions. I'm using numpy.hstack().

```
    import numpy as np
    first = np.array([[[1,2], [3,4]],
                      [[5,6], [7,8]],
                      [[9,10],[11,12]]])
    second = np.array([[[88],[88]],
                      [[88],[88]],
                      [[88],[88]]])
    output = np.hstack((first,second))
    print (output)
```

This results in an error:

**Exception has occurred: ValueError**
all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 1all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 1

Now, if I try this on two 2D arrays with a mismatched second dimension, np.hstack() has no trouble. For instance:

```
    import numpy as np
    
    first= np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
    second= np.array([[88],[88],[88]])
    output = np.hstack((first,second))
    print (output)
```

outputs, as expected:

```
    [[ 1  2 88]
     [ 3  4 88]
     [ 5  6 88]]
```

The result I'm going for with the 3D concatenation is:

```
    [[[ 1  2 88],[ 3  4 88]]
     [[ 5  6 88],[ 7  8 88]]
     [[ 9  10 88],[ 11  12 88]]]
```

Am I going about it the right way? Is there an alternative? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `np.hstack` says it concatenates on **second axis**.  You want the last, the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) is what you're looking for:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> first = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(3, 2, 2); first
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]])
>>> second = np.repeat(88, 6).reshape(3, 2, 1); second
array([[[88],
        [88]],

       [[88],
        [88]],

       [[88],
        [88]]])
>>> np.concatenate((first, second), axis=2)
array([[[ 1,  2, 88],
        [ 3,  4, 88]],

       [[ 5,  6, 88],
        [ 7,  8, 88]],

       [[ 9, 10, 88],
        [11, 12, 88]]])
```